# Url is changing when searching in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search, url

I am using sharepoint 2013. When I enter the following url in my browser and press on enter I something strange:

http://intrasp2013.demo.myCompany.biz/Paginas/default.aspx?k="thisIsAnTestSearchAction)(IsDocument:1)(path:"http://intrasp2013.demo.myCompany.biz/kennisbank")

After pressing on enter I see some text in the search inputbox. See also printscreen. In this text I see that the url is changed. See printscreen. So the domain is changed in this search input box.

Why, why why?? I realy dont understand where this is coming from!

[image]

It looks like there is some redirect setting somewhere in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure about 2013 but this type of thing happens in 201 when your AAMs are not configured correctly or your staring search URL is incorrect in your search settings.

I would check the crawl log and ensure you have the alternate access map pings correct. Otherwise sharepoint will not translate the URL correctly.

AAM = Alternate Access Mappings.  Its how SharePoint translates urls that point to the same content.  For instance, if you need different URLs for Internal, External, or Custom configurations, you can set that in the AAM.  SharePoint will take care of substituting the URL as needed when data is accessed from that site. Here is a good artical about them:

[Alternate Access Mappings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/25/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx)

To verify your starting crawl path go to Cental Administration and under Application Management click Manage Service Applications.  From there select your Search Service Application and click Manage.

On the left navigation you will see a link for Content Sources.  Click the link and it will show your available content sources.  Edit your content source and you will see the start address defined on that page.  If you put in your URL here, this is where the crawl for that particular content source will begin.

Comment: What do you mean with AAM? And where can I find the starting search url? there are many search options in site settings and central admin.

Comment: I updated the post with more information.

Comment: I agree, check alternate access mapping and ensure that your Zones are "aligned". By that I mean that the zone URL you are searching from should be the same zone for your results unless the default zone will suffice. Most folks don't know what's up with AAM until they start using Search.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is if you are querying for anything from your site collection, it redirects you to SharePoint search centre.  Then the results are display there. SharePoint search centre entirely is a different site collection used only for search pages.

Also, you can verify this thing by going to 'Site Settings -> Search settings (under search)' for your site.